# jQuery delay and get php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some problems with jQuery.
I have code that is running ok, but I want to add some delay (fade in, etc...) on this both functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".product-item, .rade-test").mouseover(function(){
        $('.just-to-define').removeClass('rade-test-div');
        $('.just-to-define').addClass('rade-test-div2');
        $('.heredefine').removeClass('rade-test');
        $('.heredefine').addClass('rade-test2');
    });
    $( ".product-item, .rade-test" ).mouseout(function() {
        $('.just-to-define').addClass('rade-test-div');
        $('.just-to-define').removeClass('rade-test-div2');
        $('.heredefine').addClass('rade-test');
        $('.heredefine').removeClass('rade-test2');
    });
});
```

I tried with

```
$(".product-item, .rade-test").mouseover(function(){
        $('.just-to-define').removeClass('rade-test-div');
        $('.just-to-define').addClass('rade-test-div2');
        $('.heredefine').removeClass('rade-test');
        $('.heredefine').addClass('rade-test2');
    }, 2000);
```

but that's not working from some reason. I don't know why. So here when it have to add class i need fade in/delay/'process time', and i already tried with `.fadeIn("slow")`

Second what I have problem with this is, I have table foreached in my template, and when mouse is over table (see in jQuery function) it's opening every class that i have write (rade-test-div2 and rade-test2), and when I add .first() it's only first ofc. How can I open only table where is my mouse?
product-item class is in TR element of table, so I can add something like

```
@php $uniqueId = uniqId(); @endphp
<tr class="product-item {{$uniqueId}}">
```

But how to write in jQuery to select this $uniqueId? My jQuery code is in another file.

Answer (score 0):

1. To make an animation, use a CSS "transition" property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions. Then, when a CSS class will be added to an element, the animation will be triggered.
2. To manipulate the active element use "this", e.g.:

```js
$(".product-item, .rade-test").mouseover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.find('.just-to-define').removeClass('rade-test-div');
    $this.find('.just-to-define').addClass('rade-test-div2');
    $this.find('.heredefine').removeClass('rade-test');
    $this.find('.heredefine').addClass('rade-test2');
}, 2000);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8vjmhztr/2/

Comment: What should I write in $(this); ? Cause like this is not working.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's working but my find function don't work, cause I have to add class to specific div with class.

Comment: Yea I found it. It's because I have to select div but not td/th... When i change to th it's ok but with div does not work. Any solutions?

Comment: I don't know what is your HTML markup, but check this example, with working "find" method: https://jsfiddle.net/8vjmhztr/3/